# Unable to Capture Bootstrap Model using Javascript

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal

below is my HTML model,

```
<
```

And below is my JavaScript.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
alert("Script is on");
$("#portfolioModal1").on('show.bs.modal', function () {
    alert('The modal is about to be shown.');
});

$( "#portfolioModal1" ).on('shown', function(){
    alert("Shown!");
});
});

$("button").click(function find_route_time()
{
    // This function is tested and is working fine.
});
```

I tried solution from many tutorials, but this is not working. I am unable to understand why? My javascript should generate alert when the Model Opens up but nothing happens.

And below is the link,

```
<a href="#portfolioModal1" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#portfolioModal1">
                    <div class="portfolio-hover">
                        <div class="portfolio-hover-content">
                            <i class="fa fa-plus fa-3x"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
             <img src="img/portfolio/EAST-CLICK.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                </a>
```

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: I cannot capture the event when model opens up

Comment: `.on('shown.bs.modal', ...` should do the trick. Do you have only one modal with `#portfolioModal4` id?

Comment: In shown.bs modal after function() you have missed open curly braces { and there is no event "shown" in bootstrap 3 version. So you do not need that. Just put { in shown.bs.modal after function( )

Comment: No I have 4 models  in total, and "#portfolioModal4" is the fourth model.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fix for your code:

Add Button to your html code as showing below:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>
```

Replace your JS code with below code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $("#myBtn").click(function(){
    $("#portfolioModal4").modal("show");
});

  $("#portfolioModal4").on('show.bs.modal', function () {
        alert('The modal is about to be shown.');
});

  $("#portfolioModal4").on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        alert('The modal is fully shown.');
});
 });
```

Note - if you want to open popup on page load event then just remove the click event from the script but the issue will be it just going to capture `shown` event.

let me know if you find this useful.

Here is completed Tested file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet"   href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
     <a href="#portfolioModal1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#portfolioModal1">Open Popup</a>
     <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="portfolioModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
            <div class="lr">
                <div class="rl">
                </div>
            </div>
            .....................SOME CODE.....................
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert("Script is on");
        $("#portfolioModal1").on('show.bs.modal', function () {
            alert('The modal is about to be shown.');
        });

        $("#portfolioModal1").on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
            alert("Shown!");
        });
    });
    $("button").click(function find_route_time() {
        // This function is tested and is working fine.
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am using model as a link, `<a href="#portfolioModal1" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">`. And want the model to show alert when the link is clicked.

Comment: your link is missing `data-target` attribute, replace your link with this one `<a href="#portfolioModal1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#portfolioModal1" >`

Comment: it should work, if not then you must have an error in your JS script, try to put entire JS file to get it sorted out.

Comment: Going to add complete new tested file for you in my answer according to edited question.

Comment: I have edited my answer according to your script, check it out there is complete source file. I have tested as well.

Comment: you can match up with your current script.

Comment: You have just added data-target option in link.

Comment: I copied your code in a file and run and it is working for me as well... But I don't know what is wrong with my actual html code, which I am running in wamp eight now. It is not responding as expected. I edited the code but still of no use.

Comment: Try to check error logs from browser console, also check bootstrap JS file as well as jQuery file make sure they are properly added to the page.. I hope this helps you.

Comment: Can you help me figuring out the error If I share the complete code of Model? Because I think there is something wrong in modal.

Comment: do you have github account? it is going to help more, if not you can edit the question.

Comment: Yes! I do have a git hub account.

Comment: Great, go ahead and commit your code with repo and share the link of your repository so that I can review and update.

Comment: checked your code, you have't added correct files there is only README.md file.

Comment: Check this out => https://github.com/kitkat225/Bootstrap-Model/blob/master/PortfolioModal1-Complete